# How do I enable transparent huge pages by default on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, huge-pages

How do I enable transparent huge pages by default on Ubuntu?

```
~$ uname -a
Linux yoda 3.5.0-23-generic #35~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 25 17:13:26 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
~$ cd /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/
/sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage$ ls
defrag  enabled  khugepaged
/sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage$ cat enabled 
always [madvise] never
/sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage$ sudo echo always > enabled 
-bash: enabled: Permission denied
/sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage$ sudo ls
[sudo] password for <...>: 
defrag  enabled  khugepaged
/sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage$ sudo ls
defrag  enabled  khugepaged
/sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage$ sudo echo always > enabled 
-bash: enabled: Permission denied
/sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage$ cat enabled 
always [madvise] never
```

Comment: In `sudo echo always > enabled`, the I/O redirection runs as the current user, not root. Try `sudo bash -c "echo always > enabled"`.

Comment: @DrKitty I wish you had given this as an official Answer so I could vote it up!

Comment: You can also use `echo always | sudo tee /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled`. Can't remember where I saw it being used that way, but it beats `sudo su -c "..."` IMHO. I added as a comment because this is a runtime setting, Rancor has provided the right answer for setting it as default.

Comment: @DrKitty if you make u make ur answer an answer i'll upvote it

Comment: The command line "sudo echo always > enabled" should be : sudo sh -c "echo always > enabled"

Answer (score 20):

Adding the following:

```
transparent_hugepage=always
```

to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT in your:

```
/etc/default/grub
```

and doing a:

```
update-grub
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 5):

```
sudo su
password: [....]
echo always > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
```

Comment: Beware that doing this will only enable THP until the next reboot. The question was how to enable it by _default_, for which @Rancor answer is the right one.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your /etc/rc.local:

`echo always > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled`